# When Google shows single result as two separate ones?

Tags: google-search

Why / when / in what conditions Google can show exactly the same result as two separate ones?

Example query:

https://www.google.pl/search?q=self-desctruction+torpedos#q=self-destruction+torpedoes

Example screeenshot:

[image]

What am I missing in this case?

Answer (score 3):

One of those links is for `google.ch`, the other is `google.com`. It's as simple as that.

Comment: I don't think this answers the "doubled entry" problem / question at all. Google operates its search engine services under 180+ domains, if I'm not mistaken, yet we don't see 180 copies of each search result, right?